# In node.js, when to use events, when to use a straight callback function?

Tags: javascript, node.js, events, callback

It seems to me that the "core" node.js callback syntax, i.e.

```
function foo(data, callback) {
  callback(false, data2);
}
```

is semantically superseded by events, except that

- With events, you lose the last bit of static checking
- Events are more flexible
- Once you have more than 2 or 3 callback-y functions, callbacks get rather clunky
- Events might be a very slight perfomance overhead (but premature optimization would be an understatement in almost all cases)
- (But then again, you have to memorize the events, too...)

So what would be a good policy for when to use what?

Comment: Depends from person to person. I would add promises to the discussion here. I personally prefer promises instead of events, because events often gets a little out of hand and might leak into modules or packages you do not want. Promises are a little more straight forward and prolly a little more clunky from time to time. Anyway, just search for promise vs. events and you get a million of blog posts with reasons for both.

Answer (score 2):

A good policy is to use whatever abstraction best models your use cases

I think performance is a non-issue in this case.

If you are providing a function to a client that performs an asynchronous call, exposing it as a single function (like your example) would seem to be completely valid, and seems to be pretty clean. (this seems to be the way most of the node.js db clients work).

Callbacks quickly get out of hand, when there are more than 2-3, as you mentioned.  But would a 2-3 callback function be better modeled as an event emitter?? Maybe, and that's up to you.

IMO 2-3+ callbacks would definately be better modeled using promises, as the calling structure would be flatter.

IMO Event Emitters are often used in longer standing objects.  Objects that are alive for a "longer" duration.  Where you would like to create an object and subscribe to events over some period of time, which seems to be a completely different use case than a single async function that exposes a callback.

Another option is to model your client as a stream.

I think a good rule of thumb is to see where node standard library (and popular node libararies) applies event emitter to clients, vs where it provides a callback based api to clients.

Node models its tcp client/server as an event emitter